# Behavior of parenthesis in the shell invoked from make

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I'm building a Linux from scratch on my old Android phone in a chrooted environment (which can be part of the problem), on a mounted ext4 partition on the sd card. I managed to cross compile install most of the stuff I need to build locally there. I installed the latest release of everything.

And now time to make something in place without cross compilation.

I decided to make and install inetutils-1.9.4.

The configure runs just fine, but when I try to make, it just fails without saying a thing:

```
# make                                                                         
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/inetutils_build'
Making all in lib
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1491: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/inetutils_build'
make: *** [Makefile:1428: all] Error 2
```

So I looked at the generated makefile and it contains this rule:

```
$(am__recursive_targets):
    @fail=; \
    if $(am__make_keepgoing); then \
      failcom='fail=yes'; \
    else \
      failcom='exit 1'; \
    fi; \
    dot_seen=no; \
    target=`echo $@ | sed s/-recursive//`; \
    case "$@" in \
      distclean-* | maintainer-clean-*) list='$(DIST_SUBDIRS)' ;; \
      *) list='$(SUBDIRS)' ;; \
    esac; \
    for subdir in $$list; do \
      echo "Making $$target in $$subdir"; \
      if test "$$subdir" = "."; then \
        dot_seen=yes; \
        local_target="$$target-am"; \
      else \
        local_target="$$target"; \
      fi; \
      ($(am__cd) $$subdir && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $$local_target) \
      || eval $$failcom; \
    done; \
    if test "$$dot_seen" = "no"; then \
      $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) "$$target-am" || exit 1; \
    fi; test -z "$$fail"
```

After inserting some echos I have found that the line with the $(am__cd)... fails, and the ored expression runs which exits the script with failure. So I attempted to find out which command fails there, and inserted some echos within the parenthesis, like this:

```
  (echo "1" && $(am__cd) $$subdir && echo "2" && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $$local_target && echo "3") \
  || eval $$failcom; \
```

Now it prints:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/inetutils_build'
Making all in lib
1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1491: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/inetutils_build'
make: *** [Makefile:1428: all] Error 2
```

However I wanted to make sure the echo doesn't fail, so I added another one.

```
  (echo "1" && echo "1b" && $(am__cd) $$subdir && echo "2" && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $$local_target && echo "3") \
  || eval $$failcom; \
```

When I tried it. It again prints just 1.

I didn't give it up just yet.

I wanted to make sure echo really fails within the script.
So I tried adding new statements into the script, before the problematic command:

```
  (echo "A" && echo "B"); \
  (echo "X" || echo "Y"); \
  echo "N" && echo "M"; \
  (echo "C" && echo "D"); \
```

It prints:

```
A
X
Y
N
M
C
D
```

Then it prints

```
1
1b
2
```

and starts building!

I'm totally puzzled here. Why does the first two parenthesized expressions fail, but not the last one?
In fact even writing `(true) || echo "ooops"` fails at first, but not when I paste it below the ored X Y parenthesis. Apparently the ored parenthesis "fixes" it, whatever state it got stuck on.

What is going on?

It should be noted I cannot reproduce this at the shell prompt but only the statements inserted into the makefile does this.

EDIT:

By removing the @ from the beginning it echoes back the command but nothing else, no errors:

```
fail=; \
if (target_option=k; case ${target_option-} in ?) ;; *) echo "am__make_running_with_option: internal error: invalid" "target option '${target_option-}' specified" >&2; exit 1;; esac; has_opt=no; sane_makeflags=$MAKEFLAGS; if { if test -z '1'; then false; elif test -n 'arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi'; then true; elif test -n '4.2' && test -n '/tmp/inetutils_build'; then true; else false; fi; }; then sane_makeflags=$MFLAGS; else case $MAKEFLAGS in *\\[\ \    ]*) bs=\\; sane_makeflags=`printf '%s\n' "$MAKEFLAGS" | sed "s/$bs$bs[$bs $bs   ]*//g"`;; esac; fi; skip_next=no; strip_trailopt () { flg=`printf '%s\n' "$flg" | sed "s/$1.*$//"`; }; for flg in $sane_makeflags; do test $skip_next = yes && { skip_next=no; continue; }; case $flg in *=*|--*) continue;; -*I) strip_trailopt 'I'; skip_next=yes;; -*I?*) strip_trailopt 'I';; -*O) strip_trailopt 'O'; skip_next=yes;; -*O?*) strip_trailopt 'O';; -*l) strip_trailopt 'l'; skip_next=yes;; -*l?*) strip_trailopt 'l';; -[dEDm]) skip_next=yes;; -[JT]) skip_next=yes;; esac; case $flg in *$target_option*) has_opt=yes; break;; esac; done; test $has_opt = yes); then \
  failcom='fail=yes'; \
else \
  failcom='exit 1'; \
fi; \
dot_seen=no; \
target=`echo all-recursive | sed s/-recursive//`; \
case "all-recursive" in \
  distclean-* | maintainer-clean-*) list='lib libinetutils libtelnet libicmp libls src telnet telnetd ftp ftpd talk talkd whois ping ifconfig doc man tests' ;; \
  *) list='lib libinetutils libtelnet libicmp libls src telnet telnetd ftp ftpd talk talkd whois ping ifconfig doc man tests' ;; \
esac; \
for subdir in $list; do \
  echo "Making $target in $subdir"; \
  if test "$subdir" = "."; then \
    dot_seen=yes; \
    local_target="$target-am"; \
  else \
    local_target="$target"; \
  fi; \
  (CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd $subdir && make  $local_target) \
  || eval $failcom; \
done; \
if test "$dot_seen" = "no"; then \
  make  "$target-am" || exit 1; \
fi; test -z "$fail"
```

EDIT 2:

Thanks for the tips, I added `set -x` to the beginning of the rule. These are the commands:

```
+ fail=
+ target_option=k
+ case ${target_option-} in
+ has_opt=no
+ sane_makeflags=w
+ test -z 1
+ test -n arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
+ true
+ sane_makeflags=-w
+ skip_next=no
+ for flg in $sane_makeflags
+ test no = yes
+ case $flg in
+ case $flg in
+ test no = yes
+ failcom='exit 1'
+ dot_seen=no
++ echo all-recursive
++ sed s/-recursive//
+ target=all
+ case "all-recursive" in
+ list='lib libinetutils libtelnet libicmp libls src telnet telnetd ftp ftpd talk talkd whois ping ifconfig doc man tests'
+ for subdir in $list
+ echo 'Making all in lib'
Making all in lib
+ test lib = .
+ local_target=all
+ CDPATH=:
+ eval exit 1
++ exit 1
```

Comment: `$(am_cd)` has completely different meanings in make and shell -- in make, it's a variable substitution; in shell, it spawns a subprocess, runs a command `am_cd` within it, string-splits and glob-expands that subprocess's output, and then substitutes the array resulting from those operations into the new command.

Comment: Frankly, just deleting the `@` character that disables proper logging for this action (so you can see what `make` is actually running) would be a help. Once you've narrowed down whether your unexpected behavior is in what's in the variables which `make` is expanding, or in the shell's execution of the results of those expansions, you can narrow the tags on this question (I'd actually expect the issue to be an autotools/automake thing, but it's almost two decades since anyone paid me to be an expert on that subject, so I've expunged it from my head).

Comment: Agreed, makefiles where rules begin with `@` are very hard to manage; that should be avoided.  If you want to debug more about complicated recipes you can add `set -x;` to the beginning of the recipe and the shell will print all the commands it's running.

Comment: Can you confirm that `lib/` exists in your working directory? That line looks as if it was intended to look elsewhere for it.

Comment: @Beta Typcially when building GNU tools the build directory where you invoke the configure script is not the same directory where the sources are (to avoid littering into the source dir). So that directory exists in the source directory but not in the build directory.

The thing builds just fine on my dev PC. But not on the device.

Comment: I wasn't asking where it ought to be, I was asking where it is. That part of the command is broken, but the cause of the break appears to be "upstream", in the code you haven't posted. You appear to have run into the usual problem with debugging generated code: whether to fix the generator, or abandon it.

Comment: @Beta But we moved away from the original topic. The question is why inserting `(true || true)` anywhere before the problematic line makes it magically work? It looks like somehow the exitcode gets stuck in the system somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put `SHELL := /bin/bash` at the top of your makefile?   Otherwise, make(1) tends to invoke `/bin/sh` as the shell, which has very different properties.